# What is the best way to filter a list using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In C#, I have a `list` of type *class Invoice* where I want to filter out those elements which has `isSelected` property `True`

```
ListA.Where(x => x.IsSelected)
```

Like I want to remove those elements from the list which have `isSlected==True` and save the removed elements into another list, so that at the end of the process I have two lists:

- ListA: elements with IsSelected==true
- ListB: elements with IsSelected==false

How do I achieve that through LINQ queries?

**Note: If the queries are kept as short/optimized as possible, will really help.**

Comment: Short or optimized? They're opposite goals in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Should look somhow like:

```
    var ListA = ListWithAllElements.Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList();
    var ListB = ListWithAllElements.Except(ListA).ToList();
```

An other possibility could be:

```
    var ListA = ListWithAllElements.Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList();
    var ListB = ListWithAllElements.Where(x => !x.IsSelected).ToList();
```

It's up to you to decide which one you do like moore.

Comment: I still have much to learn about LINQ...pretty slick.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani the most important thing about LINQ you need to know that every access to an ienumerable linq result reevaluates the query.

Comment: Yes...Yesterday, I was trying to pass a query expression as a parameter...it wasnt happening.

Comment: Did you mean...var ListB = ListWithAllElements.Where(x => !x.IsSelected).ToList();?

Comment: @ChrisCatignani yes. You can either query for all elements except ones where IsSelected is true, or you can query for all elements where IsSelected is false.

Comment: I meant that you maybe have a typo...

Comment: @ChrisCatignani you are absolutely right, thank you for the advice.

Comment: *every access to an ienumerable linq result reevaluates the query* - I think you should expand on this; as written I'm not sure I agree (or I misunderstood what you meant). It sounds like you're saying `list.Where(...).Where(...).Select(...).Where(...).Select(...)` runs the query 5 times..